# Grid MVC how to add the details section

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have been using Grid.Mvc to display some records for a while now, however as more and more properties have been added to the model, the grid has become ugly and too busy.

So I revisted the Grid.Mvc documentation pages and realised that in the demo provided:

http://gridmvc.azurewebsites.net/

They are rather neatly displaying full details of the record in a `div` on the right hand side of the page under the title **Order details**, meaning the actual grid does not get bogged down with the finer details.

I want to implement this to my project but I cannot work out how this works, there seems to be no documentation on the website that I can find that explains this, even though it seems to be used in every example they show. When I click view source I cannot see any source for how the data is being retrieved asynchronously per row.

How do I add a details section for each selected row as per the example linked?

**edit: Object im passing back as JSON**

```
public class MasterEmailViewModel
{
    public int EmailId { get; set; }
    public int MvpId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public string AddressLineOneOld { get; set; }
    public string AddressLineTwoOld { get; set; }
    public string AddressLineThreeOld { get; set; }
    public string AddressLineFourOld { get; set; }
    public string AddressLineFiveOld { get; set; }
    public string PostcodeOld { get; set; }

    public string AddressLineOneNew { get; set; }
    public string AddressLineTwoNew { get; set; }
    public string AddressLineThreeNew { get; set; }
    public string AddressLineFourNew { get; set; }
    public string AddressLineFiveNew { get; set; }
    public string PostcodeNew { get; set; }

    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    //navigation prop
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done the exact same thing with one of my projects.

The example is just using a jquery `$post`

**View**

```
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-3 col-md-push-9">
    <h4>Order details
    </h4>
    <div id="emailId">
        <p class="muted">
            Select order to display detailed infomation
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="firstNameId">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-9 col-md-pull-3">

//Grid stuff
</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {

    // ordersGrid is what you called your Grid e.g. @Html.Grid(Model).Named("ordersGrid")

pageGrids.ordersGrid.onRowSelect(function (e) {
        $.post("/Home/GetOrder?id=" + e.row.OrderID, function (data) {
            if (data.Status <= 0) {
                alert(data.Message);
                return;
            }
            // Replace the data
            $("#emailId").html(data.EmailId);
            $('#firstNameId').html(data.FirstName);
        });
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetOrder(int id)
{
    // Get the data
    return Json(data);
}
```

Comment: Does the <div class="row"> rwap around <div class="col-md-3 col-md-push-9"> and <div class="col-md-9 col-md-pull-3"> As your seem to be missing a closing div tag?

Comment: Also should the Controller method have been called GetOrder?

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem when mixing my own code with the example! :)

Comment: Do I need to pass a Json object back to the view? Im trying to pass the view model back like this: return Json(emailViewModel); but the #order-content does not seem to be updating.

Comment: Very confused, ive debugged and the only thing that is not working now is the replace the data part, if I stick an alert above the $("#order-content").html(data.Content); line it does indeed alert and ive inspected the packets and the data is being returned serialized as JSON, it just doesn't seem able to replace the order-content html?

Comment: your `data` object you are passing back to the view, what does it consist of? What type is it? Because `Content` is a property. if you have a complex type you will need to specify your properties. If you post you Model in your original post I can update my answer to reflect it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84588/discussion-between-jamie-rees-and-selectdistinct).